# Output data exceeds its limit [20480]

Tags: shell, switch-statement, oozie, oozie-workflow, capture-output

I am currently using Oozie to call Shell script. On base of exit value of the called shell script, Oozie goes to next node which is a decision node .in order to use the decision node I am using capture-output tag but thats failing with error Output data exceeds its limit [20480].

I have set the property oozie.action.max.output.data to 20480 still the oozie workflow is failing .Without the capture-output tag I am not able to use the decision log .please tell me an alternative to this??